# Need Cloudwatch rule (scheduled one) that runs only once

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron, amazon-cloudwatch

I've understood AWS Cloudwatch [Scheduled Rules](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html) (Amazon EventBridge Rules) which works by defining CRON expression.

The documentation mentions rules that triggers repetitively on a given time. Such as, run a Cloudwatch rule every 15 mins and so on.

What I want is a Rule that runs only ONCE. Any ways to achieve it? For example, run a rule after 1 hour from now, and thereafter it should never run.

Any solution?

PS: I've checked event based rule also but I don't have any event that can trigger rule.

Comment: You can make your code create a cloudwatch rule that runs every hour and then on the first trigger delete that rule again.

Comment: what actually that target for that Rule? if it's one time, perhaps we can directly trigger that target rather than having a rule?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a CRON expression in CloudWatch Events (or EventBridge) that only specifies one point in time by simply not using wildcards/repeats in the CRON expression.

> For example, run a rule after 1 hour from now, and thereafter it should never run.

While you cannot directly express "one hour from now on" in a CRON expression, you *can* build a CRON expression that will specify that absolute point in time, such as:

```
cron(0 15 2 3 ? 2021)
```

if today were the second of March 2021, at 14:00 o'clock. So, this is the CRON expression you'd use to say "one hour from now".

Answer (score 0):

You can use the new AWS EventBridge Scheduler feature

https://www.beabetterdev.com/2022/11/12/aws-eventbridge-scheduler-tutorial/?_gl=1*f8oym1*_ga*MTU0MTE2NjgxOC4xNjc4ODk4NjE2*_ga_9YXSREER7T*MTY3ODg5ODYxNS4xLjAuMTY3ODg5ODYxNS4wLjAuMA..&_ga=2.4920816.2115715245.1678898616-1541166818.1678898616

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-amazon-eventbridge-scheduler/